# Any tool to annotate a method so that method do not produce logs

Tags: java, junit, annotations, slf4j

I have some JUnit tests. In the tests i test cases where it goes into exception blocks in the testing method. And they logs errors, which ends up in my junit test results. I can do a slf4j configuration and omit the whole class from logging. But I wish for something where I can just annotate the test method and what ever code runs by that will not produce any logs.

Answer (score 0):

(a) You can use two loggers, default for class and one method-specific in your method:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourService.class);
private static final Logger customLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourService.class.getCanonicalName() + "#yourMethod");
```

(b) Or you can adjust your logging system just in test setUp/tearDown:

```
@SetUp
public void setUp() {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourService.class);
    ((LoggerImlpementationClass) log).setLogLevel(...);
}
// the same, but reset, in tear down method.
```

However in this case it will be required to change logger dependency scope from runtime to test (in maven terms).